# Code being stuck in the loop while reading from process output

Tags: python, subprocess

This code never prints "hello". Not sure why?

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
'./lite-client -C ton-lite-client-test1.config.json -D ./ton-db-dir',
stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
shell=True)

line = proc.stderr.readline()
while line != "":
    print(line)
    print(len(line))
    line = proc.stderr.readline()
print("hello")
```

Once it prints everything from `stderr` it's still not printing "hello". `stderr` is finite, it prints about 20 lines on startup.

Any thoughts?

Update: `stderr` comes from long running process. I want to interact with this process, send commands and read output.

Update 2: I made workaround that works, I added `break` if string contains specific substring.

Comment: Well what stderr are you sending into this script?

Comment: *"stderr comes from long running process"* But that doesn't tell us what the stderr was, and it isn't reproducible. On SO you're required to post a repducible example [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I was able to easily repro with `perl -le 'for my $i (1..20) { warn "Not hello $i"; sleep 1 }'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to repro the problem by substituting

```
subprocess.Popen(
    ['perl', '-e', 'for my $i (1..20) { warn "Not hello $i"; sleep 1 }'],
    ...) # no shell=True; see below
```

The output from `stderr` is `bytes` here. You can add `text=True` to the keyword arguments, or change to `while line != b""`.

Also, tangentially, you can easily [get rid of the pesky `shell=True`.](/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

```py
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(
  ['./lite-client', '-C', 'ton-lite-client-test1.config.json', '-D', './ton-db-dir'],
  stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
  text=True)

line = proc.stderr.readline()
while line != "":
    print(line, end='')  # line already has a newline
    print(len(line))
    line = proc.stderr.readline()
print("hello")
```

I would perhaps also change to `while True:` and then `break` when the line is empty, so that you don't have any repeated code.  I didn't make that change here just to make it easier to compare our programs.

Comment: Suggest you should add the repro instructions to this answer.